# Can we say "the must info" in the sense of valuable information?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I heard the phrase once but don't know the context of conversation. Additionally, is "the must info" grammatically correct?

Comment: As you *heard the phrase* you probably mistook *most* for *must*. For example, "The most info I can give is...." and "It's the most info we have to date" are acceptable. Moreover, it's difficult that someone ever speaks two or three words isolated from context.

Comment: Thank you.Regarding the context: I've heard it as the last phrase and it sounded like "It's the must info".

Comment: By context we mean the social situation and the full surrounding sentences.

Comment: It "sounded like" is not very helpful, is it? What was the context, what were the people discussing about? What was said *before* and *after*? Where were you? What were the people doing? Were the speakers American, Irish, Scottish? Accents also play an important role in how a non-native speaker perceives a word is pronounced.

Comment: Thank you, Mari-Lou, for your commitment. It was a small talk between two business analytics, both fluent in American English. Unfortunately, the surrounding sentences can't be provided.

Comment: Perhaps "must have info"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very brief answer: it would be highly inadvisible to use this construction in any variant of English I’m familiar with.

It sounds to me as though it might be something that could appear in Indian English (reminiscent of “do the needful”, etc.), but since I am only very superficially familiar with Indian English, I cannot really say anything about that for sure.

When doing a simple Google search for “the must information” in quotes, I get only about 30 hits in total, which are all:

- related to various Master of Urban Secondary Teaching programmes;
- excerpts from a whole slew of statistics books (talking about something called Must analysis, which logically has Must-information), and books that deal with how to program things for Must analysis; and
- typos and misprints for “the *most* information”

This confirms that “the must information” is not a collocation used by native speakers of English.

*Must* is originally a verb, but can also be used as a noun, meaning something that is absolutely essential and cannot be foregone.

In general, nearly all nouns in English can be used as *noun adjuncts*, which basically means that they are used like adjectives. That is, at least theoretically, also possible for *must*, and the OED [does list an adjectival sense of the word](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/124225) with a few citations spanning from 1912 till 1992:

> A must story from the publisher takes precedence over all other stories. *(1992)*

Despite this, I would maintain that such usage is vanishingly rare in normal English, particularly in written or formal contexts. It might well be used colloquially, where a broader spectrum of context is available and humoristic playing with the language, sometimes stretching it to the absolute ends of its abilities, is more likely to be understood than in writing where the written word is the only hint available … but it is certainly not common, even there, and my gut feeling is that a majority of native English speakers would find the construction jarring and ungrammatical.

Note that *must* is also a noun (also spelt *musth*) that refers to the [rut](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rut?searchDictCode=all#rut-2) of larger animals—so you can have an elephant or a bull in *must(h)*. That word is a completely different one: it comes from an Old Persian word *mast*, meaning ‘drunk’, that is etymologically related to Old English *mete* and current Scandiwegian *mat/mad*, both meaning ‘food’. This *must* **can** be used as an adjective, to describe the animal in question (a *must(h)* elephant); but in this sense, “the must information” would end up being semantically quite bizarre, liking ‘information’ to some large animal that is in rut.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and answer. I also did a search for the phrase in quotes and gave almost the same. However, the note about the musth is very helpful.